# builtins.ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'itemadapter'

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to run to spider on scrapyhub and getting this error. But this spider working well on local machine. I already change the name of spider project and spider module.

```
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 103, in _create_engine
        return ExecutionEngine(self, lambda _: self.stop())
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/core/engine.py", line 70, in __init__
        self.scraper = Scraper(crawler)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/core/scraper.py", line 71, in __init__
        self.itemproc = itemproc_cls.from_crawler(crawler)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/middleware.py", line 53, in from_crawler
        return cls.from_settings(crawler.settings, crawler)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/middleware.py", line 34, in from_settings
        mwcls = load_object(clspath)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/utils/misc.py", line 50, in load_object
        mod = import_module(module)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
        
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
        
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
        
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
        
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 618, in _load_backward_compatible
        
      File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
        
      File "/app/__main__.egg/internbit/pipelines.py", line 10, in <module>
        
    builtins.ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'itemadapter'
```

Comment: locally do `python -m pip freeze`. Do you see a package named `itemadapter`. If so you need to `pip install` that.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But I solved this issue.I create a requirement.txt file. and configure it into the scrappinghub.yml file then deploy it again and it worked.                                                Note:In requirement.txt I only specify the ```itemadapter``` module.

Answer (score 3):

Just install it:

```
pip install itemadapter
```

BTW, itemadapter is a scrapy module rather than a built-in module.